# how to enable ALOGD in android?

Tags: android, logging, android-camera

In CPP code, for ex in camera HAL, ALOGD messages are not being printed.
Like in set_preview_window()
ALOGD("set_preview_window : X, rc %d", rc);
How to enable them?

Comment: you want to get logs from CPP Code ?

Answer (score 5):

try to add following statements in the files which you wanted to catch logs.

```
#define LOG_NDEBUG 0
#define LOG_NIDEBUG 0
#define LOG_NDDEBUG 0
```

After compiled, you can try to get logs through adb logcat.

Answer (score 3):

These macros (ALOGX...) are defined in some system core C/C++ headers.
You can find an example in **system/core/include/log/log.h** (AOSP 6.0.0r1)

Sometimes you need to add **liblog** in LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES of the corresponding Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ... liblog
```

Also, you might need to add two lines **at the top** of C/C++ concerned source files :

```
 #define LOG_NDEBUG 0
 #define LOG_TAG "LibName"
```

Don't forget *LOG_NDEBUG 0* if you want ALOGV() logs.
After rebuilding the lib/module, you should be able to see logs in your logcat.

Answer (score 2):

See the definition of `ALOGD` to get a hint.

In my case i had to do

```
setprop persist.testapp.debug.log 5
```

5 was debug level.

Answer (score 1):

To get logs from CPP to Android you ca use the following

```
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "%s", Str);
```

and to use this you need to import the following library

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

if you Want o get simple logs you ca use the following

```
LOG("Add description here");
```